# TextInput inside a FlatList

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Description

From the sample code below, the FlatList returns n-number of TextInput, when a value is entered on a particular TextInput it keeps re-rendering every other TextInput.

Sample Code

```
<FlatList
    ...........
    renderItem ={this.renderItem}
/>

renderItem=(item)=>{

   <Text>{item.name}</Text>
   <TextInput
   .........
   onChangeText ={(text)=>this.setState({text})}
   value={this. state.text}
/>

}
```

Solution

I have tried to assign a key to the TextInput but don't know how to go about it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: Added Complete Example

You need to maintain textinputs state as an array to store the values for each textinput

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

export class Demo extends Component {
  state = {
    textInputs: [],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  height: 100,
                  backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
                  width: 300,
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  margin: 10,
                }}
              >
                <TextInput
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
                  }}
                  onChangeText={text => {
                    let { textInputs } = this.state;
                    textInputs[index] = text;
                    this.setState({
                      textInputs,
                    });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.textInputs[index]}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    flex: 1,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                  onPress={() => {
                    let { textInputs } = this.state;
                    textInputs[index] = '';
                    this.setState({
                      textInputs,
                    });
                  }}
                >
                  <Text> Clear</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to set the textInputs[] to empty after an onPress event

Comment: @D.Moplio is that Button will be in each item of FlatList or It will be separate ?
If it that button is for each item inside  flatlist then you can do onPress={ let { textInputs } = this.state
         textInputs[index] = "" 
          this.setState({textInputs}) // reset to empty string}

Comment: thanks @Ayush Nawani, I have tried this solution before now but the entered value isn't cleared from the TextInput. i also tried using this.ref.textInput.clear() and      setNativeProps({text: ' '}) same issue

Comment: @D.Moplio sorry my bad, there were few issues in my previous code. You can check my main updated answer, I have updated it with a complete example. Thanks. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Yea i tried it, still experiencing same issue, entered value not cleared from the input

Comment: well, that is weird because for me above example is working on both Android and iOS. Did you copy complete code example?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, i didn't notice because it was kinda slow. i guess its because the data in my FlatList is from a remote api

Comment: @Moplio That's great. Please accept my answer if it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: @AyushNawani Please have a look at https://snack.expo.io/BJGMscqsS Bad luck is on device after typing a single character, keyboard goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `value` attribute from your `TextInput`, *but this is not the solution* as the value is stores into single state only, so if you want to get value of multiple textinputs you have to create rowrender and array of states

```
<TextInput
    .........
    onChangeText ={(text)=>this.setState({text})}
    //value={this. state.text}
/>
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://snack.expo.io/BJGMscqsS


Bad luck is on device after typing a single character, keyboard goes down.

Comment: @MayurBaldha I seen above answer later, that was the best way to implement this feature with any element which uses inside Flatlist. So try that one instead of my answer.

Comment: :it's not working check 



From the sample code above i am trying to render textbox along with content inside Flatlist renderItem method and simultaneously trying to update textbox value.

Bad luck is on device after typing a single character, keyboard goes down.